# issue with cordova in vistual studio 2015

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2015

I am using visual studio 2015 to work with cordova.

I created simple project and copy it to www

I choose Andriod and Device and then run

I got error 
Could you please advise me how to solve this issue ?

```
1>  ------ Building platform: android (TaskId:11)
1>  Debug (TaskId:11)
1>  ------ Build configuration options: --debug (TaskId:11)
1>  Running command: cmd "/s /c ""C:\Users\i053322\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat" --debug"" (TaskId:11)
1>  ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\i053322\AppData\Local\Android\sdk (TaskId:11)
1>  JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_55 (TaskId:11)
1>  Running: C:\Users\i053322\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b C:\Users\i053322\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true (TaskId:11)
1>   (TaskId:11)
1>  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. (TaskId:11)
1>   (TaskId:11)
1>  * Where: (TaskId:11)
1>  Script 'C:\Users\i053322\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\platforms\android\build-extras.gradle' line: 1 (TaskId:11)
1>   (TaskId:11)
1>  * What went wrong: (TaskId:11)
1>  A problem occurred evaluating script. (TaskId:11)
1>  > Could not find property 'MissingTranslation' on com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.LintOptions_Decorated@2cca98. (TaskId:11)
1>   (TaskId:11)
1>  * Try: (TaskId:11)
1>  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. (TaskId:11)
1>   (TaskId:11)
1>  BUILD FAILED (TaskId:11)
1>   (TaskId:11)
1>  Total time: 11.058 secs (TaskId:11)
1>  Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M (TaskId:11)
1>   (TaskId:11)
1>  C:\Users\i053322\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126 (TaskId:11)
1>                      throw e; (TaskId:11)
1>                            ^ (TaskId:11)
1>  Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s /c ""C:\Users\i053322\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\platforms\android\gradlew" cdvBuildDebug -b "C:\Users\i053322\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\platforms\android\build.gradle" -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true" (TaskId:11)
1>  Command finished with error code 1: cmd /s /c ""C:\Users\i053322\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat" --debug" (TaskId:11)
1>ERROR building one of the platforms : error : cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
1>  You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project (TaskId:11)
1>MDAVSCLI : error : cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
1>Done executing task "MdaVsCli" -- FAILED. (TaskId:11)
1>Done building target "BuildMDA" in project "BlankCordovaApp2.jsproj" -- FAILED.: (TargetId:11)
1>
1>Project Performance Summary:
1>    33454 ms  C:\Users\i053322\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2.jsproj   1 calls
1>              33454 ms  build                                      1 calls
1>
1>Target Performance Summary:
1>        0 ms  BuildOnlySettings                          1 calls
1>        0 ms  AfterBuild                                 1 calls
1>        0 ms  BeforeBuild                                1 calls
1>        0 ms  CoreBuild                                  1 calls
1>        2 ms  CompileTypeScript                          1 calls
1>        6 ms  PreComputeCompileTypeScript                1 calls
1>       14 ms  _CheckForInvalidConfigurationAndPlatform   1 calls
1>     4016 ms  InstallMDA                                 1 calls
1>     4019 ms  EnsureNodeJsRequirementsAreAtCorrectVersion   1 calls
1>    29412 ms  BuildMDA                                   1 calls
1>
1>Task Performance Summary:
1>        0 ms  AssignTargetPath                           1 calls
1>        1 ms  MdaVerifySetup                             1 calls
1>        2 ms  Message                                    2 calls
1>        6 ms  VsTsc                                      2 calls
1>       17 ms  CreateBuildInfoMetadata                    1 calls
1>     4015 ms  RunMdaInstall                              1 calls
1>     4017 ms  CallTarget                                 1 calls
1>    29393 ms  MdaVsCli                                   1 calls
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:33.42
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you install Cordova / Taco using Visual Studio?

When you say "I created simple project and copy it to www" that has me wondering since that would not be needed if the project was created by Visual Studio 2015.  When you go to create a new project in VS does it give you the option for "Cordova project?"

If you did install with VS it seems like something has broken the linkage to the tools from VS (this error: " You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project ").  Download Path Editor 2 (link below) and make sure your path does not have any invalid entries in it.

Make sure you have 2015 with Update 3 of the Cordova tools installed using the VS installer.  This will ensure you have the right android sdk and tool chain to do builds.

If you installed with VS then you might need to run the android SDK manager and install updated packages.

Path editor:
https://patheditor2.codeplex.com